# Service Disabled - The Push service is disabled for the application Id

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

This morning I tried to trigger my MobileFirst Starter App including the Push Service for iOS 8. On doing an authenticated and authorised REST-POST request to send a notification, I got the following error message:

> {"message" : " Service Disabled - The Push service is disabled for the
>   application Id .", "code" : "FPWSE1007E", "docUrl" :
>   "https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#troubleshoot/errors/mobilepush/index.html/errorcodes.html"
>   }

The same error will be shown when sending notifications from the Bluemix dashboard.

I also tried to restart the MobileFirst Starter application. Yesterday everything worked fine.

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Did your Bluemix trial expire?   When the trial expires (30 days), services are disabled.  You can re-enable your services by entering a credit card.  Since you are able to enter the Bluemix dashboard, is it possible the following is the case?

1. Trial expired
2. You entered your credit card
3. You are now in this error state since the service was not properly re-enabled upon (2) occurring.   We do have a current issue that re-enablement of services after (2) takes some time to occur.  We are working to improve the service re-enablement time.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your reply. None of the above cases is valid for my account.

Comment: My 30-day trial expired (-34 days). I requested to convert the account to the new Standard Account. But I still cannot add services. Also, nothing happens when I click the Credit Card button. I'm trying to go through the "Bluemix Essentials" course on developerWorks (https://developer.ibm.com/courses/all/bluemix-essentials/)

Answer (score 1):

As of April 10th, the Bluemix iOS 8 MobileFirst **beta** services have been disabled. You will continue to see this error until you delete the beta services and bind the new IMF services.

You can find more information about the new pricing plan switch in Stacy Timann's blog, [The fast track for enterprise mobile apps: IBM MobileFirst Platform for iOS](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/03/30/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-for-ios/).

Apologies for the inconvenience and enjoy the MobileFirst services, now out of beta!